# Q: How to get the result of a case to use it in another operation? | SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use a result from that CASE
I need the result of that CASE for an operation that i am going to do later.

````
SELECT p.cedula"RUN POSTULANTE",p.nombres ||' '||p.appaterno ||' '|| p.apmaterno "NOMBRE POSTULANTE",
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.fecha_nac)"EDAD",
CASE
WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.fecha_nac)<30 THEN '200'
WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.fecha_nac) BETWEEN 30 AND 40 THEN'150'
WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.fecha_nac)>40 THEN'100'
END "PTJE.EDAD",
COUNT(rp.postulacion_nro_folio)"CARGAS FAM.",
CASE 
WHEN COUNT(rp.postulacion_nro_folio)>4 THEN '200'
WHEN COUNT(rp.postulacion_nro_folio)BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN '100'
WHEN COUNT(rp.postulacion_nro_folio)<2 THEN '50'
END"PTJE.CARGAS FAM",
ec.descripcion "EST.CIVIL",```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can't reference that expression's **alias** in the same query *as it is*, one option is to use current query as a CTE and then use `CASE`'s alias. Something like this:

```
with temp as
  (select p.cedula, p.nombres, ...
          --
          CASE when extract...       --> CASE we're talking about is here
          END as edad
   from ...
  )
-- now you can use it
select a.some_column,
       --
       t.edad                       --> it is used here
from some_table a join temp t on ...
```